# How can I change all these settings from my Ubuntu Bash Terminal?

Tags: 20.04, bash, gnome-terminal, gui, system-settings

I have Ubuntu 20.04 system. *My windowing system is X11.* Here is my settings dialog box :

[image: Settings Dialog Box]

I have often noticed that I can't change all the settings from terminal alone. I have to use the mouse many times and interact with the GUI to get things done. How can I change all these settings from my terminal without using the GUI?

For example, in the pic given above, no matter whether I add proxy to the `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, `/etc/environment`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` files via terminal, I always had to set the proxy via GUI settings too otherwise my web browser won't be connected to the Internet, although my terminal is connected to the Internet.

In short, my goal is to not use mouse at all, except for shutting down. Is there any way to do this? Is there any software that will completely make me get rid of the mouse?

Comment: How exactly did you try to add the proxy in each of those files? Did you log out and log back in afterwards? Why are you using the global configuration files for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, in Linux, all settings can be changed from the command line. A factor that brought Linux to the desktop is the development of graphical mouse driven tools that expose some settings to less technically proficient users.

The Gnome Settings dialog just exposes a user interface for a range of settings, actually a small subset of possible options, that can be stored in different ways. There is keyboard support, but indeed it sometimes is very clunky.

Many settings, and actually much more than are exposed to the user, can be configured through `dconf` or `gsettings`. The following command lists all settings:

```
gsettings list-recursively
```

A setting can be read with the `gsettings get` command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-1
```

and changed with the `set` command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-1 "['<Super>1','<Super>W']"
```

and reset to default with the reset command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-1
```

To be complete - but this is a GUI program, these settings can also be inspected and changed using `dconf-editor`.

Other settings, such as the network configuration, are stored in dedicated configuration files, in specific locations and specific formats that depend on the software package. Commonly, these are formatted plain text files that can be edited using a terminal or using text processing tools of the shell such as `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, etc. In some cases, the software may provide command line tools to change options.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can also add many of these commands in my scripts.

Comment: @vanadium why is the reset  line identical to the  get  command despite referring to resetting it via a  reset command?

Comment: @GWD The last argument is not there, but indeed `set` should read `reset`. Thanks for pointing this out: I have corrected this!